# Receiving List object from javascript to Java Struts2 using json

Tags: json, ajax, struts2

```
var data = {
        'students': [{
            'intStudID': 1,
            'strFName': 'John Angelo',
            'strLName': 'Castillo',
            'strMName': 'Castillo',
            'strAddess': 'Meycauayan, Bulacan',
            'strContactNo': '12313131'
        }, {
            'intStudID': 2,
            'strFName': 'Jeff',
            'strLName': 'Santos',
            'strMName': 'Santos',
            'strAddess': 'Pasig',
            'strContactNo': '12313131'
        }]
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'createStudents',
    method: 'post',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

});
```

This is my code in js.

```
public class CreateStudentsAction extends ActionSupport{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

public String execute(){
    System.out.print(students.size());
    if(StudentRepository.createStudents(students) == true)
        return SUCCESS;
    else
        return ERROR;

}

public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
    this.students = students;
}
}
```

I'm getting 0 when printing the size of students.
It won't accept objects from ajax. I hope there's somebody who can help me in my problem.
---updated---
this is student class

```
public class Student {

private int intStudID;
private String strFName;
private String strLName;
private String strMName;
private String strAddess;
private String strContactNo;

public Student(int intStudID, String strFName, String strLName, String strMName, String strAddess,
        String strContactNo) {
    super();
    this.intStudID = intStudID;
    this.strFName = strFName;
    this.strLName = strLName;
    this.strMName = strMName;
    this.strAddess = strAddess;
    this.strContactNo = strContactNo;
}
public int getIntStudID() {
    return intStudID;
}
public void setIntStudID(int intStudID) {
    this.intStudID = intStudID;
}
public String getStrFName() {
    return strFName;
}
public void setStrFName(String strFName) {
    this.strFName = strFName;
}
public String getStrLName() {
    return strLName;
}
public void setStrLName(String strLName) {
    this.strLName = strLName;
}
public String getStrMName() {
    return strMName;
}
public void setStrMName(String strMName) {
    this.strMName = strMName;
}
public String getStrAddess() {
    return strAddess;
}
public void setStrAddess(String strAddess) {
    this.strAddess = strAddess;
}
public String getStrContactNo() {
    return strContactNo;
}
public void setStrContactNo(String strContactNo) {
    this.strContactNo = strContactNo;
}
```

Comment: does struts 2 accepts JSON?

Comment: yes we've tried it before. but we're having problem when it comes to objects

Comment: what type constrcutor do you have for `Student`

Comment: @ScarWombat, already updated.

Comment: @JeffreySantos There should be default constructor and it doesn't have `null` values.

Comment: Show your action configuration.